# Reason for downvoting the question

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I want to know the reason of downvoting the below question. I observed someone had downvoted the question twice. Can you say the reason.. so that I will take care while posting the question.

[**My Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426746/how-to-generate-following-graph-in-html)

Comment: One person can only vote on a question (/answer) _once_.
We can't tell you what reason that person downvoted you for, as that's something only the voter knows. Sure, we can speculate, but that would just be... speculation.

Comment: My ___guess___ would be that the reason is that your code shows no effort of trying to solve the issue, yourself.

Comment: [Start here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [then here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Since you don't have the `Informed` badge, I can be pretty sure you haven't read the former.

Comment: Hi thank you all for your suggestion. I tried lot of API, also tried to customize few of them but I found difficulty to achieve it. Even all combination of google search (whatever I tried, doesn't given me any similar result). So the reason behind asking the question is to get suggestion on is there any API is providing this kind of graph.

Answer (score 7):

This question is awfully broad. Answering it takes a lot of code, and there isn't going to be one good answer, but a bunch of possible answers.

That makes this question not really suitable for SO. You should narrow it down, maybe by adding your attempt and telling where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi Patrick, one simple question I want to ask to you, if you are fine than only I will ask (else you guys may downvote). Does asking a simple question is a crime in your site (SO). I felt this is a site to help people.. but no issue.. still I like this site it is very much helpful... (hard luck for me, I felt very bad about such a negative response to my question..) I tried my best by sharing screen shot for my requirement with explanation and I asked only reference site not the code... Sorry for taking your time (if you feel bad, than you are free to further downvote my question)

Comment: You can ask any time. The problem is that your kind of questions are seen as 'give me the code' questions. People hate those since they usually mean 'I don't want to make any effort. Give the code for free'. That is the reason you attrack many downvotes with your question.